# Making content of a certain fragment invisible when an user is not registered

Tags: firebase, android-studio

Suppose I have a fragment account and there are three ways to access my app Register, Login and Skip for now. If an user clicks on skip for now, the components of my account fragment should be hidden and instead of all that, there must be one login button.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, it is helpful for the community if you provide some more details of the attempts you've made so far. Please review the guidelines here:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain it by setting a variable in shared preferences or you can set a global variable on the base of user's entry choice. Accordingly manage visibility of the content.